# Can h:CommandLink POST to an external URL?

Tags: jsf, seam

I'm working on a Seam application and need to submit some form data to an external URL only I'm a bit stumped as to how I should approach it.

h:CommandLink is the ideal tool only it doesn't seem to be able to POST to an external URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a normal HTML form. Since there's nothing to bind to your business/model layer, you don't need JSF components at all.

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to send actual managed bean property as input params of the vanilla form used above? Any stack link already?